# Prototype Ajax.Request not excecuting in some cases

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In bottom of my index.php I have a `Javascript` function between paired `<script>` tags. I have a click handler that calls the function that makes a `Prototype.js` Ajax request.

This version does not work (no request is made), although the `myFunction` itself is called.

```
function myFunction(fr, fw) {
    new Ajax.Request('/ascript', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { a: fr, b: fw }, 
        onSuccess: function(transport) { }, 
        onFailure: function(request) { }
    });
}
```

However when I add the alert("something"); line the ascript php script is called.

```
function myFunction(fr, fw) {
    new Ajax.Request('/ascript', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { a: fr, b: fw }, 
        onSuccess: function(transport) { alert("here"); }, 
        onFailure: function(request) { }
    });
}
```

Might it be some weird whitespace problem? Is there an error in my syntax?

Comment: How do you know that the request isn't made? Have you tried installing the Firefox "TamperData" plugin to trace HTTP requests, or even Firebug?  Simply changing the callback like that should have no impact on whether the HTTP request is made, so either it *is* being made, or else there's something else different about the second test.

Comment: The script where the request is made is my own, and I have error_log sentences there, I can see that it is not excecuted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the problem. The problem was in how I added the eventhandler to my "button"

Initially (on both examples given in my question) I had:

```
echo "<a href='' ><p id='button' onclick='myFunction(" .$a .", " .$b.");'>Click</p></a>";
```

The surrounding `<p>` with a link tag was ofcourse a bad idea ...

This works:

```
echo "<a href='' onClick='Event.stop(event);'><p id='button' onclick='myFunction(" .$a .", " .$b .");'>Click</p></a>";
```

Thanks to all for your answers. I guess the moral of the story is, look eaven farther from the Javascript itself, look where it gets called and what could be broken there.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `onComplete` event. Prototype sometimes doesn't fall into either `onSuccess` or `onFailure` however all request will be covered by `onComplete`

also try wrapping the ajax request with `Try - Catch` block, it might help.

Comment: try catch did not help, adding alert("Blah") to onComplete ends in the same result - the thing starts working. But I don't want to show an alert everytime the request completes :)